# How to set an iTerm2 startup command

Tags: iterm

How do I set a command on a profile so that when I start a new terminal window, it fires off that command.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to set my virtualenv with:

```
workon ENV
```

So that it starts automatically into my virtual environment when that I use that profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it, there is an option added in the development branch of iTerm that adds a "Send text at start" option to the profile settings. This will eventually be added to a (more) stable version of iTerm.

Comment: How to run multiple commands one after another in same profile tab?

Comment: Can't seem to execute multiple commands either using iTerm2 - attempting to 'make configure', and then 'make service'. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: You can separate commands with a `;` and that will allow multiple commands on one line.

In this example `make configure; make service` should work.

Comment: Try `command1 && command2`

Answer (score 27):

Profiles -> General -> Command

[image: iterm-screenshot]

Everytime you open a new tab your bash profile will be sourced.

Comment: What if you only want to launch it the first time iterm2 starts up? And not every time a new tab is opened?

Answer (score 4):

In iTerm2, preferences>profiles>tab `general`, there is an option in `Command` called `send text at start` that executes any command you put there after login.

In particular, I typically have

```
source ~/.virtualenvs/.../bin/activate
```

for profiles that use Python.

Answer (score 4):

Using the image to illustrate, please note the `command` selection and `Send text at start:` option.

[image]

Comment: This should be an edit to the accepted answer  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115870/237