# How to auto source ~/.bash_profile on macbook everytime a new terminal is opened

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash

On my work macbook, it seems my `~/.bash_profile` doesn't get sourced every time a new terminal (tab or new window) is opened, and I have to do it manually. How can I automate this?

I read through [Terminal: run source ~/.bash_profile every time start new terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315985/terminal-run-source-bash-profile-every-time-start-new-terminal), but it didn't help because I don't currently use `~/.zshrc`, or `.bashrc`

I am using `Zsh` shell

Comment: There’s some missing details here like what shell are you using?  Use the command `echo $0` at the prompt to find out.  What other init files do you have present like `.bashrc` or `.zprofle`?  It helps immensely if you identify the version of macOS you’re on; please [edit] the question with that info.

Comment: Aside from considering using the appropriate bash script instead (i.e. whichever one gets run on a new terminal) I seem to recall iTerm2 has the option to configure a script to run.

Comment: @Allan It seems I am using`zsh`. The only other files beginning with `.` that I see under home is 
```.CFUserTextEncoding  .borgignore          .viminfo
.DS_Store            .borgpass            .vscode/
.Trash/              .cache/              .zsh_history
.bash_profile        .config/             .zsh_sessions/
.borgfiletest        .python_history      
.borghealthcheck     .ssh/    ```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297908/116013

Comment: Well, Zsh doesn’t source .bash_profile.  You could create a `.zprofile` with a single line that sources your `.bash_profile` but I don’t recommend that.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388622/119271

Comment: Why on earth do you want to process `.bash_profile`, a file written for bash shell language, from a different shell?

Answer (score 2):

#### Zsh ≠ Bash

As such, Zsh doesn’t source Bash’s `.bash_profile`.  You need a `.zprofile` to be configured.

One quick (and dirty) way to get what’s in your `.bash_profile` into your Zsh `.zprofile` is to issue the command:

```
echo “. $HOME/.bash_profile” >> ~/.zprofile
```

This will cause `.zprofile` to source `.bash_profile` every time an interactive shell is opened.  The commands appends what’s in the quotes to `.zprofile` - the command to source `.bash_profile`. It will create the file if it doesn’t exist.

It is much, much perferable however, to create a proper `.zprofile` because while *mostly* compatible with each other there are subtle difference that could break things (i.e. a colorized prompt).

As you’re starting with a new shell, this is an excellent opportunity to put things is the right place.  See this Q&A [ZSH: .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin - What goes where?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388622/119271) for a more detailed look into what shell configuration files go where and what they do.